# Center buttons in flex in Appbar

Tags: material-ui

I have trouble aligning/justifying as centered buttons in the AppBar. 
It looks like this (see [demo here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/centering-demo-y5tr2)):

```
<AppBar position='sticky'>
  <Toolbar>
      <div className={classes.topMenuBoxes}>
        <img className={classes.logoSize} src={LogoFull} alt="logo" ></img>
      </div>
      <div className={classes.topMenuBoxes}>
        <Button className={classes.menuText} color='inherit' >Offer</Button>
        <Button className={classes.menuText} color='inherit' >Join</Button>
        <Button className={classes.menuText} color='inherit' component={AboutLink}>About us</Button>
      </div>
      <div className={classes.topMenuBoxes}>
        <DropMenu />
      </div>
  </Toolbar>
</AppBar>
```

...and using this makeStyles:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  logoSize: {
    marginTop: '30px',
    height: '70px',
  },
  menuButton: {
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      display: 'none',
    },
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  menuText: {
    [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
      display: "none",
    },
    textTransform: 'none',
  },
  topMenuBoxes: {
    flex: 1,
  },
}));
```

How do I align content inside the divs where I have referenced classes.topMenuBoxes?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried: `alignItems: 'center'`?

Comment: If I do that on Toolbar level, it just centers all flex items, and not what is within the flex item (the three buttons). If I do it on item level, nothing happens.

Comment: Understood. I was actually looking at the standard [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/3kwos) of the AppBar and it seems that in item level the center alignment works if the position is relative on Toolbar level. I think it is worth a try in case you want to change some of your structure

Comment: Thanks- I used that to make a demo for my specific case, but still no luck. https://codesandbox.io/embed/centering-demo-y5tr2

Comment: By looking at the demo, am I assuming correctly that you want to center the buttons along with their text content? Or just their text content?

Comment: It's the buttons I'm trying to center - not just text on button (which is already centered by default)

Comment: `textAlign="center"` does the trick then, but it centers even the sidebar button on the left...

Comment: You are absolutely right - thank you!

Comment: Welcome. I am writing it as a proper answer to the question then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `textAlign:"center"` to your `topMenuBoxes`:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  // ...

  topMenuBoxes: {
    flex: 1,
    textAlign: "center"
  }
}));
```